# QML SceneLoader not displaying some objects

Tags: qt, qml, gltf

Is there a way to diagnose why `SceneLoader` in QML (Qt 5.8) might appear not to work?

In my current project, there's one (3DS) model that `SceneLoader` will show (and this worked first try), but I replace it with any other models.

I run `qgltf` on the models, load in their resource file, etc.. basically set everything up the same, but never models won't show.

My sceneloader status is also set to `ready`, as opposed to `error` when it cannot find the file.

I've noticed that if I don't scale my objects, it will appear as if their not showing, but nothing I do to the newer models (either scaling them in Blender or in a QML `Transform`) has any impact.

I once saw an app for preparing models for Qt, but I think it was discontinued, in any case I'm not able to find it now.

Is there some vertex limit?  Some other limit?  I can't find anything in the docs about why it mightn't work.

Code:

```
Entity {
   property SceneLoader shipObjSmall: SceneLoader {
      id: shipObjSmall
      source: "qrc:/models/tugboat-small.qgltf"
      // code to print status on onStatusChanged
   }
   components: [shipObjSmall]
}
```

Comment: Your declaration as a property is weird. The SceneLoader is both a property and an id, I would not be sure this works... you should be able to just delete the `property SceneLoader shipObjSmall: ` part.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference, though I completely agree.  My habit of doing this is a relic from when I started Qt and had (still have to some degree) some confusing between IDs and properties.

I suspect there's an issue with the loading or probably the model it self.. Because even if I load a `.ply` file itself (instead of the `gltf` version), it shows, but then I can't transform it with an `OrbitCameraController`, *i.e.* it's behaviour is just different.

Comment: AFAIK, Qt3D uses [assimp](http://www.assimp.org/) to load the models, you could try loading it into the [assimp viewer](http://www.assimp.org/main_viewer.html)

Comment: oh nice, I'd landed on that page a few times where it lists which models are supported, but I somehow never noticed that there's a viewer.  I'll try it out, thanks!